# Evaluating PHP Code

Tags: php, html, dreamweaver

I am very much a beginner when it comes to using PHP.  I was given this code, to try and output the contents of a files on a folder, onto a server, but my issue is I do not know how to read and alter this code to fit my specific file path.  Can someone help me out with this, and lets just use the name folder as an arbitrary pathname.

```
<?php
if ($handle = opendir('.')) {
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
            echo "$file\n";
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
?>
```

Comment: The folder is located outside of the server what effect will that have on this process

Comment: If I'm understanding your comment correctly, this code won't work if the files/directories you're trying to access are not located on the server that you're running this script on.

Comment: Yeah i think you are understanding it correctly, the folder is located on a seperate drive then the actually site, it draws from a company folder not the website

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php

$dir_path = '.';  //      '.'      = current directory.
                  //      '..'     = parent directory.
                  //      '/foo'   = directory foo in the root file system
                  //      'folder' = a dir called 'folder' inside the current dir
                  //      'a/b'    = folder 'b' inside 'a' inside the current dir
                  //      '../a'   = folder 'a' inside the parent directory
if ($handle = opendir($dir_path)) {
  while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
    if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
      echo "$file\n";
    }
  }
  closedir($handle);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$path = '.';

if ($handle = opendir($path)) {
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
            echo "$file\n";
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Detailed explanation and examples: http://www.php.net/function.opendir